# Bettas and Air ("oxygenating water")

Tags: fish, aquarium, betta

I'm about to transport a Betta on a few hours road trip for the holiday. That will mean a few hours in a jar. I know that's not ideal, but it's better than going a long period without food.

My son was worried, asking me to poke air holes in the lid.

I said that water is made of hydrogen and oxygen, and the fish will breathe with gills the way we get oxygen from the air with lungs.

A coworker said that (some) fish need their water oxygenated, but I'm not sure how that works when water is H<sub>2</sub>O?

So the questions, as I promised my son I'd ask:

- **Would the Betta require air holes in the lid of the jar?**
- **How does water become "oxygenated"?**

EDIT: If water is H<sub>2</sub>O, how does it become further oxygenated, especially if it isn't under pressure? H<sub>2</sub>O would mean that water itself is composed of oxygen and hydrogen. I don't think fish would like to breath H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub>.

Comment: Gills definitely do not break down water molecules into Hydrogen and oxygen. Air is in solution in the water, in the same manner that CO2 is in solution in soda, just at a much smaller concentration.

Comment: http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/gen01/gen01419.htm - seems to support that source of confusion for me; I was thinking that was more of a process (carbonation) that happens under pressure.

Comment: Carbonation is exactly the same principle, but higher concentrations of a specific gas dissolved into the solution. Gas in solution bahaves in many ways as the opposite as solid in solutions. A hot liquid can hold more solid in solution, but less gas. That why warm soda fizzes more and goes flat faster, but hot honey (a supersaturated solution of sugars) gets thinner when you heat it.

Comment: bringing your fish is not better than going whitout food a fish have no problem going without food for a week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are three ways to oxygenate water in an aquarium:

- **Aeration:** this is the process in which air and water are brought into intimate contact. usually this is done by the aquarium filter and air pumps.
- **CO<sub>2</sub>/O<sub>2</sub> exchange by plants:**
  with proper lighting plants exchange CO<sub>2</sub> for O<sub>2</sub>.
- **Diffusion:**
  this is when adding two solutions each with different concentration - this would be your water changes.

In your case you are transferring the Betta, so what you need is mostly aeration. So yes, you have to let air pass through, the best thing to do is to allow it's way into the jar with an opening because few hours are not really few for the oxygen the jar.

Answer (score 2):

Without the gas exchange across the surface, the water will lose its oxygen rather quickly. He would be alright depending on how long the trip is, but quite a few things happen in that water while he is being transported. The fish will make waste and respire which creates ammonia and nitrates. When the ammonia concentration increases in this container it'll bring the pH down slowly, which will eventually neutralize the ammonia. However, once the jar is open it will rapidly come back up and the ammonia will become toxic again - which is why when shipped fish are unbagged, most people immediately net them to prevent that shock from happening.

Also, these guys have labyrinth organs which they use to breathe air just like we do :) So he draws from the water and air. It's best to find something you can give a few holes to safely, or remove the lid during the trip now and then to allow that gas exchange to happen. Betta can easily go a few days to a week without eating; while not ideal, they will be alright. Some folk also set up timed, automatic feeders for their fish as well. I hope this helps and gives you some leads for what to do with your small tropical fish friend. :)

Comment: Ammonia is basic in water and it will bring the pH up, I think what you meant was carbon dioxide lowering the pH - CO2 is acidic. Fish respiration through gills releases both ammonia and CO2. The lower pH is, the more dissolved ammonia exists in the ionized ammonium form, which is non-toxic. Opening the bag makes the dissolved CO2 outgas from water and this raises pH up; ammonia is much more soluble in water than CO2, so it stays there. Increase in pH converts non-toxic ammonium to free ammonia, which is highly toxic. However, besides that detail, your answer is correct, so I v*ted up.

Comment: And also, I don't think fish excrete nitrates; yes, they excrete ammonia, but the source of nitrates in aquarium water is bacteriogenic and not piscine in origin.